# Sublime text 2 - How to run a shell command over ssh?

Tags: bash, editor, sublimetext2

I'm new to *Sublime Text 2* and there's something I haven't figured out yet, how can I run a bash command over SSH ?

For example, to view the *Apache* error log on my dev server, I'd like to be able to run :

```
ssh root@192.168.0.2 "tail -10 /var/log/httpd-error-user.log"
```

Instead of having to open a terminal, I'd like to run this from within the editor with a keyboad shortcut.

I've read about [build systems](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html), but I'm not sure it's the way to go, also it seems to allow only one command.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'll answer my own question. You can easily create a build pointing to any script, so all I had to do was create `myscript.sh` containing :

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh root@192.168.0.2 "tail -10 /var/log/httpd-error-user.log"
```

And then create a new *Build System* in *ST2* to call it :

```
{
    "cmd": ["./myscript.sh"]
}
```

**Note** : In this example (i'm on Linux), `myscript.sh` is located in `/home/mike/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/User/`

Comment: You can make this even better by creating a build system that works generically.  i called mine ```rsync local to remote.sublime-build``` and in it i put: ```{ "cmd": ["$project_path/rsync.sh"] }```. That will run ```rsync.sh``` in the root of your Sublime Project.  then you can have different rsync flags, servers and paths per project.

Comment: Is `$project_path` a Sublime variable? Is it available just when having a `sublime-project` saved? For the moment I solved quickly doing `cd path/to/script/dir/ && ./myscript.sh`.

Answer (score 9):

If You are on a windows machine, You could try this:

1. Install [Putty](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/putty-0.63-installer.exe). You we'll need `plink` from this package.
2. Update Your `PATH` variable with Putty install directory.
3. Create a Build System in Sublime

   ```
   {
    "cmd": ["plink", "-pw", "<password>", "<userid>@<remotehost>", "./your-script.sh"]
   }
   ```

I use it for remote `make`, works quite good.

**Note** that your password is plain text here. I know it's no good ;]. This is just an example. To fix it keybased login could be used. Google *PuttyGen* and *autologin*.

Comment: making through SSH was precisely what I needed. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried looking into [Sublime SFTP](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp) plugin?